# RCRD_DSNT_EXIST","message":" There are no records of this type - Extended

Tags: javascript, workflow, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Okay everyone, very much through the looking glass on this one. Many thanks to Barmar, Kryton and bknights whose wisdom has helped get me this far.

The script has changed and is now below. I can upload it and generate a script record and it does actually attempt to run, but now I am getting this error:

"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"RCRD_DSNT_EXIST","message":"There are no records of this type.","stack":["createError(N/error)","initiateWorkflow(/SuiteScripts/grn20.js:9)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"RCRD_DSNT_EXIST","details":"There are no records of this type.","userEvent":"aftersubmit","stackTrace":["createError(N/error)","initiateWorkflow(/SuiteScripts/grn20.js:9)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}

But the record definitely does exist, the ID number and workflow ID are as specified in the workflow.

What else could be causing this problem?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

**Edit - I have been told that the record ID below should refer to the internal ID of the item, this makes no sense, the workflow I am trying to initiate is designed to change fields on multiple items, why would I need to specify a single item in the script?**

*Edit 2 - Reposted as I am not sure questions show in feeds if they have been answered.*

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

define(['N/workflow', 'N/search', 'N/error', 'N/record'],
    function (workflow, search, error, record) {
        function initiateWorkflow(scriptContext) {
               var workflowInstanceId = workflow.initiate({
                recordType: 'inventoryitem',
                recordId: 35,
                workflowId: 'customworkflow14'
            });
            var inventoryitemRecord = record.load({
                type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
                id: 35
            });
        }
        return {
            afterSubmit: initiateWorkflow
        };
    });
```

Comment: A workflow targets a specific record type and is triggered in one of two ways: 1) Event Based, in which case an event on a record of the targeted type triggers the workflow, or 2) Scheduled, in which case an instance of the workflow is triggered for each result returned by the specified saved search.  In either case, the workflow instance needs an internal ID matching a record of the targeted type, to know which specific record to target.  Not sure if that helps make anything clearer, but there is a fundamental misunderstanding in your bold edit above.  Hope that helps clear it up.

Comment: Thanks Krytpon. My impression was that it is possible to manually activate a workflow via a script in a move that would negate the specified schedule or event and cause the actions specified within the workflow to activate when the script was run. From your answer this is evidently not the case, and to me represents a deep flaw in Nestuite. I am not a programmer, but I have made a number of workflows, but the 30 minute scheduling is a limitation, I need the actions to happen in real time when new goods are received and the average costs change. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The Netsuite documentation states this - " 
Initiates a workflow on-demand. This method is the programmatic equivalent of the Initiate Workflow Action action in SuiteFlow.

Returns the internal ID of the workflow instance used to track the workflow against the record."

Which I feel is misleading and creates the impression that you can initiate a workflow on demand using a script.

Comment: OK, first: I could be wrong about some of this, so don't take it as gospel - be curious, experiment and try to think about what's happening behind the scenes when you get results/behaviors you weren't expecting.  Second: NetSuite's documentation leaves a lot to be desired, although it has gotten a lot better than 7 years ago when I was in your position.  That said, my understanding from a combination of the docs, and my observations, the API calls a *single instance* of the workflow.  If you look at the docs for Initiate Workflow Action you can see how this makes sense - see next comment.

Comment: Use the Initiate Workflow action to initiate another **workflow instance** from the current workflow instance to process multiple workflows in parallel. The workflow instance initiated with the Initiate Workflow action, or child workflow, **runs on the same record** instance as the parent workflow instance. For example, if a workflow instance running on a purchase order initiates a child workflow instance with the Initiate Workflow action, both workflow instances run on the same purchase order.

Comment: Previous comment is an extract from (Initiate Workflow Action)[https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11513].  If you need to programmatically call the workflow on a number of items, you can simply create a a list (array) of the items (or item ids) and loop over them.  Or loop over the lines of the transaction, if that applies.  Also, consider making your workflow an event based workflow rather than scheduled, then you're not subject to the 30 minute limitation.

Comment: Thank you Krypton. I managed to get it working in the end.